# Can't mount tmpfs to container

Tags: docker, centos6, kubernetes-pod, tmpfs

I'm trying to start kubernetes worker on CentOS 6.8 with docker 1.12.6.
There is no success when weave container starting, it cannot get token from mounted tmpfs volume.
I tried to start container in console with that same volume and don't see files from mounted dir.

Docker 1.12.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 does not have this problem.

Directory that I'm trying to mount:

```
tmpfs on /var/lib/kubelet/pods/92b7bed4-2231-11ea-bfc2-56d198239b85/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/weave-net-token-4gzn9 type tmpfs (rw)
```

My command:

```
docker run --privileged=true --rm -it  -v /run/xtables.lock:/run/xtables.lock -v /var/lib/kubelet/pods/92b7bed4-2231-11ea-bfc2-56d198239b85/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/weave-net-token-4gzn9/:/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ -v /var/lib/kubelet/pods/92b7bed4-2231-11ea-bfc2-56d198239b85/etc-hosts:/etc/hosts -v /var/lib/kubelet/pods/92b7bed4-2231-11ea-bfc2-56d198239b85/containers/weave-npc/a0d27baa:/dev/termination-log weave-npc-my sh
```

Command `ls -la /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/` shows nothing.